"ERROR: FreeType version 2.3.0 or higher is required" when building openjdk6 even though get freetype installed
Problem summary
I am building openjdk 6 on aarch64 linux, when it comes to make sanity step, I am informed of an error ERROR: FreeType version  2.3.0 or higher is required., but i have already installed freetype.
Environment
Kylin V10 and aarch64
openjdk6 source code(.zip) was downloaded here and README-builds.html was refered for building instruction.
Reproduce the problem

unzip  jdk6-master.zip to unzip the src compressed package
cd  jdk6-master to enter the src directory
run bash and . jdk/make/jdk_generic_profile.sh according to README-builds.html
run make sanity, here comes the ERROR: FreeType version  2.3.0 or higher is required.
run yum install -y freetype-devel to install freetype
run make sanity again, but the error still exists. I check the freetype installation by running freetype-config --version to get:

[root@DC1-04-005 jdk6-master]# freetype-config --version
23.2.17

What I've tried
I run yum list freetype --showduplicates and get
[root@DC1-04-005 jdk6-master]# yum list freetype --showduplicates
Last metadata expiration check: 1:43:58 ago on Fri Apr 19 08:39:44 2024.
Installed Packages
freetype.aarch64                                                                        2.10.2-3.ky10                                                                        @ks10-adv-os
Available Packages
freetype.aarch64                                                                        2.10.2-3.ky10                                                                        ks10-adv-os

The version of installed freetype is 2.10.2-3.ky10, I am confused which version of freetype was installed? 2.10.2-3 or 23.2.17?
I run find / -name freetype and get

[root@DC1-04-005 jdk6-master]# find / -name freetype
/usr/share/licenses/freetype
/usr/include/freetype2/freetype

Then I run export ALT_FREETYPE_HEADERS_PATH=/usr/include/freetype2/freetype to help make   variables locate my freetype, but it doesn't help and the error still exists.
Run make sanity | grep FREETYPE and get:
[root@DC1-04-005 jdk6-master]# make sanity | grep FREETYPE
  FREETYPE_HEADERS_PATH = /usr/include/freetype2/freetype
    ALT_FREETYPE_HEADERS_PATH = /usr/include/freetype2/freetype
  FREETYPE_LIB_PATH = /usr/lib
    ALT_FREETYPE_LIB_PATH = /usr/lib
make: *** [make/sanity-rules.gmk:57: post-sanity] Error 1

How can I solve this problem? Is the version of installed freetytpe too high or something else?
Btw, is there any good advice on building openjdk6 in aarch64 linux? So far as I have learned, there is no jdk5 or jdk6 for aarch64 platform for bootstap jdk and I am now using jdk8 as a substitute.
